# SSAS: sum over time, average everything else

Tags: ssas

I have a measure in a fact table that I would like to sum over the time dimension and after do the average in all other dimensions. The order matters!

What is the best way to achieve that? Is there some SemiAgregration function in SSAS that provides this out of the box? Should I add MDX script to achieve that behaviour?

Thanks,

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "average in all other dimensions"? In most cases the "AverageOfChildren" implemented by Analysis Services is not what you want, as it calculates an unweighted average. Would summing across all dimensions and then dividing by "the number of fact table records except for the time" (how ever this is defined in detail) give what you want?

Comment: I'm afraid I cannot picture what you mean. However, if you're saying "the order matters!" I wonder if you need to read about SOLVE_ORDER ?